# Inject values on EJB parent class

Tags: java, ejb, message-driven-bean

I have several classes that handle queues, with similar methods. I would like to move the injection part, to the parent class. But in every attempt that I have done, the injected values are always `null`.

This is one of my child classes:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;

@MessageDriven(name = "QueueMDB1")
public class Queue1 extends CommonQueue implements MessageListener {
    @Inject
    private IDao dao;
    [...]
}
```

I would like to move `dao` from classes `Queue1,2,3...` to the parent class `CommonQueue`. Which annotation the parent class should have to allow the injection (if it's possible to do that)?

Comment: From a quick look to the specs, it should work. However, I did not find a place to explicitly mention injection in MDB super classes. What you are seeing may be a bug or a gray area in the specs. Just to be sane however, you can try an alternative path, *preferring composition over inheritance*: You may factor the functionality of the `CommonQueue` in a separate, standalone CDI bean and inject and use that bean in your `QueueN` MDBs.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos yes I already did in this way, I created an interface with the getters of the dao and other variables that CommonQueue needs, I implement it in Queue1,2,... and pass it as parameter to the CommonQueue. It was just more staightforward had it injected directly on the parent class.